# Select Distinct rows with related data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following data in a table UserMgr.

```
ID  |  UserID  |  MgrDbID  |  DeptID
1   |  111     |  2        |  1
2   |  112     |  NULL     |  1
3   |  113     |  5        |  1
4   |  113     |  6        |  2
5   |  114     |  NULL     |  1
6   |  114     |  NULL     |  2
7   |  115     |  5        |  1
8   |  115     |  6        |  2
9   |  116     |  10       |  1
10  |  117     |  NULL     |  1
```

All the users including the managers are present in the above table. MgrDbID refers to the ID column. There may be multiple records for an user in which case there will 
be multiple records for the corresponding manager by DeptID. For Managers, MgrDbID is NULL.

I need the resultset as follows containing distinct UserID and UserID for the corresponding MgrDbID as follows (for users who are not managers). Can anyone please help with the query for the below.

```
UserID  |  MgrID
111     |  112
113     |  114
115     |  114
116     |  117
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select u1.userid, min(u2.userid) as MgrID
from UserMgr u1
join UserMgr u2 on u1.UserMgrID = u2.ID
group by u1.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

The above did not return desired result. The following worked for me.

```
SELECT u1.userID, u2.UserID
FROM users u1 INNER JOIN users u2 ON u1.MgrDbID = u2.ID
GROUP BY u1.userID, u2.UserID
```